# Crear una notificación persistente en Android Wear

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-wear

Me gustaría crear una notificación dentro de Android Wear que sea persistente, es decir que el usuario no la pueda descartar, solo se le permite abrir.

También como eliminar la notificación dentro de la app una vez acabado el proceso.

Así creo mi notificación:

```
   public void displayNotification() {

        Intent viewIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
        int notifyId = 0x01;
        viewIntent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_NAME, notifyId);

        PendingIntent viewPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, viewIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_local_activity_black_24dp)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                getResources(), R.drawable.bg_notify))
                        .setContentTitle("titulo")
                        .setContentText("mensage de la notificación")
                        .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getActivity());
        notificationManager.notify(notifyId, notificationBuilder.build());

    }
```

Me falta:

- Asignar la notificación que sea persisntente.
- Obtener el putExtra en MainActivity.
- Cancelar la notificación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las notificaciones en `Android Wear` son similares a las de `Android`

Para hacerla que sea persistente en `build` de la notificación `.setOngoing(true)` Se puede cerrar al hacer click si se especifica `.setAutoCancel(true)` o bien recuperar el `id` de la notificación y cerrarla con `NotificationManager.cancel(id_notificación)`

Asignar al `AndroisManifest.xml` que la actividad tenga `android:launchMode="singleTop"`

**Obtener datos extras:**

```
onNewIntent(getIntent());
...
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onNewIntent: ");
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        if(extras.containsKey("")) {
            int notifyInt = extras.getInt(NOTIFICATION_NAME,-1);
            NotificationManager.cancel(notifyInt );
        }
    }        
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

}
```